# C++ virtual templated method

Tags: c++, class, templates, polymorphism, virtual

I know this question has been answered in many different forms again and again, and is perhaps one of the most confusing points in C++'s design, but I'm trying to learn the language after many years doing many things in pure C that would be considered quite illegal in the C++ world (think function pointers juggling). I want to try educating myself to the C++ mindset before giving up and going to another language.

I just started a project in which the most fundamental component is a streaming class, and for that I wanted it to be generic: what kind of data it would stream would be up to its subclasses.

```
template <typename T>
class BasicStream {
protected:
    T *buffer;
    unsigned int bufferSize;
    unsigned int bufferPos;
    bool streamEnd=false;
public:
    virtual T read();
};
```

My idea was to chain objects together, as in the output of one object of certain class being directly read by another object of another class. But for this to work, all objects must be able to accept a generic `read()` function and return its desired type. For instance, I have a class to splice bits which accepts bytes (unsigned char) as inputs:

```
class BitExtractor : public BasicStream<bool> {
private:
    unsigned char bitMask;
    unsigned char byte;
    BasicStream<unsigned char> &byteSource;

public:
    BitExtractor(BasicStream<unsigned char> &source);
    virtual bool read();
};
```

It returns a `bool` type and needs any class which derives from `BasicStream` and has an `<unsigned char>` return type as input. My idea was to make the input completely agnostic from the data source; be it a file, an internet stream, or even some position in memory; all wrapped around classes derived from `BasicStream<unsigned char>`.

An example would be a `FileReader` class, to handle a/synchronous file loading:

```
class FileReader : public BasicStream<unsigned char> {
protected:
    FILE *file;
    bool asyncFlag;
    bool asyncOpReady;
    bool fileEnded;
    pthread_t asyncThread;
    unsigned int lastRead;
public:
    FileReader(char *fileName,int bufferSize=1024,bool asyncRead=false);
    ~FileReader();

    virtual unsigned char read();

private:
    typedef struct {
        unsigned int amount;
        unsigned int *read;
        unsigned char *buffer;
        FILE *file;
        bool *flag;
        bool *flagStreamEnd;
    } TData;
    static void AsyncRead(void *data);
};
```

Now, let's suppose I want to create a BitExtractor using a FileReader as data source.

```
BitExtractor bx=BitExtractor(FileReader("SomeFile.abc"));
bool firstBit = bx.read();
```

Internally, `BitExtractor` is calling the FileReader `read()` method. My assumption was that since `FileReader` is a class derived from `BasicStream<unsigned char>`, it should recognize the templated function.

```
BitExtractor::BitExtractor(BasicStream<UInt8> &source):bitMask(128),byteSource(source){}

bool BitExtractor::read(){
    bool bit=byte&bitMask;
    if(streamEnd==false){
        bitMask>>=1;
        if(bitMask==0){
            try {
                byte=byteSource.read();
                bitMask=128;
            } catch (...) {
                streamEnd=true;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        throw "Bytesource has ended!\n";
    }

    return bit;
}
```

Even though it does compile, it fails to link due to `vtable` errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BasicStream<bool>::read()", referenced from:
      vtable for BasicStream<bool> in BitIO.o
  "BasicStream<unsigned char>::read()", referenced from:
      vtable for BasicStream<unsigned char> in FileIO.o
```

I've already learnt though other StackOverflow questions that my code is impossible in C++, given its lack of runtime polymorphism (the compiler cannot decide which template of `BasicStream` the subclass invokes at runtime). My question is, given my data streaming/chaining pattern, is there any other more "C++ish" alternative to implementing my design, like using or subclassing something from the STL (of which I know almost nothing)?

Or is it simply unimplementable in C++?

Comment: Your code does not present the issue you speak of in your title. A template base class may introduce a virtual function (even one that depends on the class template's type parameter). Once you instantiate the template, there is only one well defined entry in the vtable.

Comment: Your problem is probably in code you don't show.

Comment: What error are you getting, its probably due to leaving something unimplemented. "my code is impossible in C++, given its lack of runtime polymorphism" !!?? Who told you this ? :) C++ supports both static and runtime polymorphism.

Comment: At a minimum, please always show the exact compiler error.  It is also extremely helpful to include enough of the implementation to allow others to try compiling.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions; I'm trying to make my question more clear. :)

Comment: @MVittiS: In BasicStream, change 'virtual T read();' to 'virtual T read() = 0;' and add a virtual destructor to it. This would make BasicStream an abstract class and compiler won't expect an implementation for the same. The error should not come after that change unless you have not provided an implementation for read in the derived classes as well.

Comment: This is a classic beginner's mistake; it would surprise me if someone didn't find an earlier question that duplicates this one.  Read up on "pure virtual functions".

Comment: As Spencer, Arunmu, and davmac pointed out, all I needed was to make it a pure virtual function. Problem solved!

Comment: `BitExtractor bx=BitExtractor(FileReader("SomeFile.abc"));` shouldn't even compile because the `BitExtractor` constructor takes its stream by non-const reference. Are you by chance using VC++, which has an extension allowing this (and then letting you enter undefined behavior when the temporary file reader goes away before you extract the bits).

Comment: I do not think it is ok to derive from BasicStream and having a member BasicStream. Does your code actually do that ? It is not necessary. It is enough to have BasicStream as a member of BitExtractor.

Comment: @Cristi there is nothing wrong with deriving from a class and having a member whose type is also that class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it stands the problem is that you declare the template member function virtual:

```
virtual T read();
```

... but you don't define it; that's why you get a link-time error - the vtable for the `BasicStream<bool>` class needs a function to point at, and there isn't one. I'm pretty sure the problem could be fixed either by making it pure virtual:

```
virtual T read() = 0;
```

... or providing a default definition.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you should use streams from the standard library.

The only nontrivial feature you mention is reading a bool from a stream, which is done with the appropriate `operator>>` of **std::basic_istream**. If you have extra special needs, you can override it in an ad hoc stream subclass.

The code in the question has the artificial limitation of pretending that a stream is a homogeneous sequence of values of a certain type, with an highly inconvenient template parameter. 
In reality a stream should be considered a source or sink of values of any type (you can read or write anything at any position) or a sequence of bytes (which are read, written, and transformed from and to values of other types). The standard library streams do both, with the overloaded and templated operator>> and operator<< and with the character-based low-level I/O and position accounting.

Comment: For one thing, standard library streams were designed to read and write formatted text. OP's code clearly indicates a desire to read binary.  OP could wrap something arund a streambuf but this only virtualizes the source end of things.  The second thing is, responses of the type "you're reinventing the wheel" do not address the question and are better left as comments than answers.

Comment: @Spencer: While the output formats differ, you can ignore the text-specific parts of the `<iostream>` design and adapt the general pattern. In particular, the idea of `T* buffer` is tricky; it means you can't mix output from two different buffer types, You'd lose the relative order. `<iostream>` buffers formatted output instead.

Comment: @MSalters But that's exactly my intent; I don't want to mix different kinds of data. Each class should only accept one type and return another (be it the same or a different type). I'm using the templating mainly to enforce this.